# serialize array inputs and send it via post jQuery

Tags: php, jquery

I'm trying to format the data to send it to the server via ajax but I can't serialize exactly the inputs to get the correct array at the end, I cannot understand what I'm doing wrong.

```
<input name="option[16]" value="Value1">
<input name="option[17]" value="Value2">
<input name="option[18]" value="Value3">

var final_options = new Array();
$('input[name="option[]"]').each(function() {
    final_options[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('value');
});
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url:"./urlPost",    
    data: {final_options: final_options},
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(data){
        console.log('Ok');
    }
});
```

On server side I need to translate it as;

```
array(
  array(
    '16' => 'Value1'
  ),
  array(
    '17' => 'Value2'
  ),
  array(
    '18' => 'Value3'
  ),
)
```

Comment: Why don't you use `$("#formid").serialize()`?

Comment: Because im not using a form, im getting the values from part of inputs.

Comment: you can serialize anything, doesn't have to be in a form. serialize will accept any dom element that contains form inputs/textareas

Answer (score 1):

Use [`.serialize`](https://api.jquery.com/serialize/). You don't need a form, you can select the elements themselves.

```
var final_options = $("input[name^=option]").serialize();
```

Note that I used an [Attribute Starts With Selector](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) to match all the `option[#]` inputs. Your selector would only match `name=option[]`, not `name=option[16]`.

On the server this will become:

```
$_POST['final_options'] = array(
    'options' => array(
        16 => 'Value1',
        17 => 'Value2',
        18 => 'Value3'
    )
)
```

In your code, `$(this).attr('name')` will be something like `option[16]`. So when you do

```
final_options[$(this).attr('name')] = $(this).attr('value');
```

you're assigning to `final_options['option[16]']`, not `final_options[16]`.

Finally, to get the current value of an input, use `.val()`, not `.attr('value')`. The latter gets the value attribute from the DOM, which is just the initial default value.

Comment: Ok, i understand you, but for this i will need to push some how the keys that are 16,17 an 18. Thx

Comment: They **are** the keys in the resulting array.

Comment: I'm not fallowing you, can you please be more exactly ?, you can just give me a link with documentation to understand how to serialize only by selecting an element,but that element contains the key inside of square brackets, so what i need is to send to the server side the key and value.

Comment: I've corrected the answer, maybe it will be clearer now. `.serialize` takes care of parsing the `name` attributes and serializing it so that PHP will turn it back into an array properly.